# Having trouble automating the opening of a non-exe file using INNO Setup and Shellexec

Tags: installation, inno-setup, shell-exec

I have done a considerable amount of searching for a solution to what i believe is a very simple answer. I am a very novice INNO Setup Users, so please excuse the question.

I have an Excel file which i want to open after installation. The install process works just fine however i am unable to have the excel file launch automatically on Setup completion. It's my understanding that ShellExec is used to launch non-exe files, however I believe i have this line incorrect.
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Here are the snippets of the code which i believe apply to this issue

```
#define MyAppName "MyApplication"
#define MyAppExeName "MyApplication.xlsm"

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
OutputDir=C:\Documents and Settings\Test\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Files]
Source: "C:\\MyApplication.xlsm"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[ShellExec]
Shellexec('',{#MyAppExeName},'','',SW_HIDE,ewWaitUntilTerminated,ResultCode)
```

Thank you for taking the time to aid me on this issue.

Comment: There is no `[ShellExec]` section at first. That section will probably be generated by some external tool. What I would do, if that excel file is a document containing readme notes, simply add `isreadme` flag at the end of your `[Files]` section entry. That will create a "View readme" check box at the final wizard page and of course open the file if that check is checked.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however i really need this to open as an Excel as its a complete application with macros and several sheets.

Comment: I don't get your note, readme files should be opened by the Shell as well.

Comment: Perhaps that is true, however i do not need a Readme file opened, i needed and '.xlsm' file opened. While i realized the Shellex was the right way to go, I still did not have the correct ShellExec code that was used to open the file until @Miral provided the correct code. Thank you for your input as well.

Comment: I just wanted to say, if you want to have, I don't know MP3 file, as a readme audio file, put `isreadme` flag to the `[Files]` entry. At the end of the installation, you'll see the "View readme" check box, which if you keep checked, it opens the file with the associated program. Nothing more or less ;-)

Comment: Ahh ok now i understand what you are saying (sorry for my lack of knowledge, this is the first time working with INNO). So if i use the  isreadme flag it will open up the file, regardless of its format 'if the "View readme" is checked. That makes sense. However what is being launched is the actual program. The [Run] parameter gives me the "Launch program now" option, which is actually what i need since the Excel file is the program. Thanks again for taking the time to explain this to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; Description: Run {#MyAppName}; Flags: postinstall shellexec
```

Replace your `[ShellExec]` section (which is not recognised by the compiler so will just be ignored) with the above.

Comment: Excellent. Thank You so much. Worked perfectly.